# Function to return ID

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there any chance to get device-uuid that remains the same between sessions or re-installs in javascript and ReactJS.

I have already used the device-uuid - npm library but the id is the same for two devices if a platform is the same.

Comment: what do you mean by re-install in react web app?

Comment: Hi ! Could you provide your targets ? Mobiles android / iOS and / or desktop browsers or else ?

Answer (score 0):

you can try device's mac address

`npm i macaddress`